# How do i apply my code to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

the code below works but what i'm trying to do is to apply to "Working 2".
I've tried:
paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1 .working2'));
but this doesn't work.

Background of the code:
Keeps looping all the elements until an empty element found. Once found, it replaces it with a variable. Then breaks the loop.

```js
paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1'));
for(const para of paras) {
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
    para.innerHTML = partnumber;
    }
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine5" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine6" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine7" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine8" class="working2"></p>
```

Comment: use `('.working1, .working2')` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll('.working1 .working2')` will select elements with `class = working2` inside `working1` use `querySelectorAll('.working1, .working2')`. 
See **[Groups of selectors on one rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule)**.

```js
paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1,.working2'));
let partnumber = 0
for(const para of paras) {
  partnumber++
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine5" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine6" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine7" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine8" class="working2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querySelectorAll('p[class^="working"]')

```js
paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p[class^="working"]'));
let partnumber = 0
for(const para of paras) {
  partnumber++
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine5" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine6" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine7" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine8" class="working2"></p>
```